# How can i add fat library in cmake

Tags: c++, ios, boost, cmake

I have build boost for iOS as fat binaries.
So i have many `boost_*.a` files with
 `arm7 armv7s arm65: i386, x86_64` (simulator) architectures. 
These libs placed in usual structure

```
boost_folder:include - boost - boost_headers
boost_folder:libs - (all libs mentioned above)
```

My question: I want to create library for iOS and link it with my boost in CMake

simple instructions like:

```
include_directory(boost_folder)
find_library(Boost REQUIRED)
```

failed to find Boost.

What can i do to find library correctly?

Comment: `find_library(Boost)` searches a *library file* named 'Boost' (possibly with 'lib' prefix and some extension like '.a'). If you want to locate Boost **package**, use `find_package(Boost)` instead.